# how to make nutch crawler crawl

Tags: nutch

i have some doubt in nutch 
while i used the wiki i am asked to edit the `crawl-urlfilter.txt`

```
+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*apache.org/
```

and i am asked to create an url folder and an list of url...

do i need to create all the links in `crawl-urlfilter.txt` and in the list of url ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

crawl-urlfiler.txt act as a filter, so only urls on apache.org will ever be crawled in your example

The url folder gives the 'seed' urls where to let the crawler start. 
So if you want the crawler to stay in a set of sites, you will want to make sure they have a positive match with the filter... otherwise it will crawl the entire web. This may mean you have to put the list of sites in the filter